# How do I defeat the marmota?

Tags: valkyria-chronicles

The question is pretty much at the title.

How do I defeat the [Marmota](http://valkyria.wikia.com/wiki/Marmota) in chapter 18 of [Valkyria Chronicles](http://valkyria.wikia.com/wiki/Valkyria_Wiki)?
I can't get near it with my tanks, it destroys any unit that approaches it. I was about to give up when I decided to give it one last try.

[image: marmota]

Comment: I have a feeling it appeared in two missions... which one is it?

Comment: On chapter 16, you only need to stall it, I meant in chapter 18, when you actually have to go for it and destroy the valkyria lance. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take out the lance, I kinda cheated and put heavy armour on the Edelweiss, drove it into the tracks in front of the Marmota so its main gun was at an angle where could hit the lance.

Otherwise, focus on taking out Lancers and Snipers first. And use your Lancers to take out the radiators to drop the shield. You will need an Engineer to restock ammo and don't be afraid to spam CP on one Lancer so you can fire off more shots at the radiators/lance.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I've tried spamming CP on one Lancer and got pwned, but the Edelweiss idea looks promising. I'll test it and if it goes well accept your answer. Thanks!